# Word describing a rule that is implemented to specifically target a small set of people

Tags: single-word-requests

Suppose I had a small company with perhaps 20 employees, and one of them had an obtrusive quirk, perhaps something like always attaching a massive number of "reaction gifs" in emails. HR might decide to create a new policy stating that there can be at most 3 gifs in an email. Is there a word for this kind of a rule that seems to apply to everyone but is really just meant for a specific set of people to tell them to stop doing something?

"HR put in some new policies but they're really just _____ rules."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the point of view of the person being specifically targeted, they might say that it's "just **persecution**," or "just **discriminatory** rules," since it targets them and not anyone else.

From the point of view of the other employees, it's "just **arbitrary** rules" because the guidelines are not meaningful or necessary for the general population.

From http://thelawdictionary.org/arbitrary/:

> **Arbitrary**: Not supported by fair, solid, and substantial cause, and
>   without reason given.

(*Law Dictionary: What is ARBITRARY? definition of ARBITRARY (Black's Law Dictionary)*)